# OP_LSHIFT & OP_RSHIFT purpose & functionality

Tags: script, opcodes

What is the purpose & functionalities of the `LSHIFT` & `RSHIFT` Script OP codes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the early versions of bitcoin the software used the openssl bignumber lib to perform left and right shift.

E.g. Look at `script.cpp` in [v0.2.13](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases/tag/v0.2.13)

For example, The `OP_LSHIFT` (L595) uses `bignum.h` (L503) and `openssl/bn.h` to define `<<` operator and ends up at this definition of lshift:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/1c0eede9827b0962f1d752fa4ab5d436fa039da4/crypto/bn/bn_shift.c#L104

It seems they were disabled in response to a DoS security concern:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Incidents#CVE-2010-5137

Answer (score 6):

For all intents and purposes, Bitcoin has no such opcodes.

Very early versions of Bitcoin's reference implementation did, until version 0.3.10 (August 2010) when they were disabled together with a number of other opcodes. New opcodes with identical functionality could be re-introduced now with a softfork, but the fact that similar opcodes existed historically wouldn't make that any easier (or harder) - they'd just be new opcodes.

As for what they did: they implemented an operation similar to the >>= and <<= C/C++ style operators, multiplying and dividing by a specified power of two.